# Toggle Class when click on element itself and remove when click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dom element:

- When I click on the element, it will toggle open and close.
- When I click on the child of the open one, it will not close the parent.
- When I click on another one, it will open the one which is clicked and close the others.
- When I click outside the element that has been opened, it will close then open.

-> The problem is I can't archive the first one. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
$(".front").click(function() {
  $(".front").not(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(n) {
  var t = [];
  t.push($(".front"));
  $.each(t, function(t, i) {
    $(i).is(n.target) || $(i).has(n.target).length !== 0 || $(i).removeClass("active")
  })
});
```

```css
.front {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.front .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 150px;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.front.active .back {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="front">
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>

<div class="front">
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>

<div class="front">
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add toggle class after your first line:

```
$(".front").click(function() {
$(".front").not(this).removeClass("active");
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

});

Comment: if use toggleClass the child inside will be toggle too, i just want the parent one to be toggle

Comment: Then add .parent after (this)

Comment: It not work in my case, when i click on the child it still toggle